# how to save surfaceview which has webcam layer on top of it as an image?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I've developed a very simple app on android to get the webcam screen on a surfaceView and now I want to capture the surfaceView as an image onto SDCard but I only end up with a black screen after saving the picture below is my full app for get webcam screen on surface and also capture the image out of surfaceView:

```
imported packages 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
```

methods for getting webcam screen on a surfaceview

```
Camera camera;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean previewing = false;

private String mScreenshotPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myimages";
//private ArrayList<Element> mElements = new ArrayList<Element>();

private Button takePicture;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    surfaceView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);


    LayoutInflater controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.control, null);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
            ,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    this.addContentView(viewControl,layoutParamsControl);
    takePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takepicture);
    takePicture.setOnClickListener(this);


}



@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                           int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(previewing){
        camera.stopPreview();
        previewing = false;
    }

    if (camera != null){
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
            previewing = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera = Camera.open();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
    previewing = false;
}
```

on the same class my approach for capturing a surfaceView as image

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "pucture saved" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    saveScreenshot();
    //takePicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private boolean ensureSDCardAccess() {
    File file = new File(mScreenshotPath);
    if (file.exists()) {
        return true;
    } else if (file.mkdirs()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}



public void saveScreenshot() {
    if (ensureSDCardAccess()) {
        //Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(surfaceView.getWidth(), surfaceView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        surfaceHolder.getSurface().freeze();
        Bitmap bitmap = surfaceView.getDrawingCache();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        //surfaceView.draw(canvas);
        File file = new File(mScreenshotPath + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("Panel", "FileNotFoundException", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Panel", "IOEception", e);
        }
    }
}
```

layouts :

```
//main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/camerapreview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

</LinearLayout>


//control.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        >
    <Button android:id="@+id/takepicture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Take picture"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"

            />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I'm able to capture surfaceView in a bitmap object but my problem is, there isn't any clue of webcam screen on surfaceView during saving it in a bitmap object.

How can I have a persistence surfaceView so I'm not gonna miss the webcam screen?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar thing where I needed to save my image with an overlay. I achieved this by first saving the captured image, then putting it back into my view, and then saving that as the bitmap. It worked well enough for what i needed.